# What does initWithCoder initialize first-time values to?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscoding, initwithcoder

I'm using NSCoding for a game I'm making to save stuff like a high score. My question is: What do these values get initially set as if they've never been saved before? Like in the first time running the app. It will decode the values, but there's no values there to begin with.

I believe that int gets set to 0. I could be wrong.
What do NSString and BOOL get set to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the key doesn't exist so any of the decode... methods will return a non-positive value. Int returns 0. Bool returns NO. Object (e.g. NSString) returns nil.